# HTML image not loading in browser

Tags: html, web-frontend

I am having problem in HTML,
Image is not loading/showing in browser **(Firefox)**.
I want to set this image as background.
My html file is in folder in D: drive and my image is F: drive. I am using   **VS CODE** (system setup), I have checked file path.

`<img src="F:/mountain.png" alt="mountain">`

Comment: you should create a folder for your entire website. Webspace doesnt work through multiple drives that easily.

Comment: As above. You should put all of your assets in a folder. If the `index.html` and `mountain.png` files were in the same folder, you would just need to use `src="mountain.png"`

Comment: Is there any way to use two different drives

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use local files in Web pages, without using web-server (like apache2 or nginx). Check developer console, you should see the error like "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: not true - just very unefficient and only works offline. Using it online will be messy because of missing read permissions.

Comment: Is there any way to use different drives (on same pc) for webspace.
I want to use local file only for offline mode.

Comment: You still can use web server, even locally. This will allow using different drives